# (How) can I display an rtf on the command line?

Tags: command-line, text-formatting, file-format

I know there are much better solutions for *writing* documents through the command line that are intended to be nicely formatted (markdown, LaTeX, troff, etc. ad infinitum), but I have not encountered any software for *viewing* RTF files on the command line.

Considering that terminals are *capable* of bold text, underlining, centered text, colored text, et. al., it would seem that it should be possible to convert the information in an RTF file into commands the terminal can understand and display.

Is this possible (perhaps even just with a Perl script) or are there technical barriers that make it impossible?

If it's possible, has such a software actually been created?  (Preferably open source such that I could improve upon it at need?)

Comment: You might want to consider this question at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

RTF files can (besides **text**) contain pictures and inserts which are not straightforward to render.

There have been a few programs named `rtf2html`, `rtf2text` (and `rtf2txt`) which you could evaluate for your needs.  For html of course, you could use one of the text browsers.  Beyond that, it's in the realm of opinion.

Here are a few possibilities:

- [rtf2html](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2html/) (fla_2, vlavrinenko)
- [rtf2html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtf2html) (npmjs)
- [RTF to HTML Converter](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTMLGeneration/rtf2html.html) (1993)
- [Rtf2Text](http://rtf2text.codeplex.com/)
- [rtf2text](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2text/) (sriramasharmaa)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unrtf` + `lynx`.

```bsh
unrtf --html x.rtf > x.html
lynx --dump x.html > x.txt
```

This handles UTF-8 properly.

From a comment on [this answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365394/406868)