# Feeding unicode to unrtf

Tags: unicode, conversion

I'm trying to convert some files that contain utf-8 characters from rtf to text but i can't get unrtf to not just remove them:

```
➜  ~ file test
test: UTF-8 Unicode text
➜  ~ cat test
eeeééééèèèèfff
➜  ~ unrtf --text test
###  Translation from RTF performed by UnRTF, version 0.21.5 

-----------------
eeefff
```

Is there any way (or another tool) to do this?

Comment: You can open a 'Rich Text File' with the editor `ted`, and save the file as **file.txt** http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/editors/ted/

Comment: The GNU manual seems to have `--noremap` which might do what you want

Comment: @Fox thanks, but the manual states that it only works for 8-bit charsets, and it does not work in my case.

Comment: @KnudLarsen, have you been able to install it on a debian 8? Ted seems to depend on libraries that are no longer available. Also, is there a way to automate it?

Comment: @iCart Does it still strip the Unicode if you convert to, say, HTML? `lynx -dump` is good for turning HTML into proper text, so that _might_ offer a workaround

Comment: »» Ted seems to depend on libraries that are no longer available «« : OK, I will try making a package.deb for Debian 8. ..... Assume 64bits OS ?

Answer (score 0):

No luck building (compiling) Ted with Debian 8 Jessie : libtiff errors (lots), but a package built on CentOS 7 works perfect with the default Debian 8 `libtiff5` !

Built from ted-2.23-1.src.rpm to ted-2.23-1.x86_64.rpm, and completely rebuilt frem the rpm package on Debian 8 to install with the right Debian dependencies ( `dpkg-shlibdeps Ted` ) ... to `ted_2.23-1debian8_amd64.deb`. Download link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUkUzV25qUURXbjA/view?usp=sharing

Installs OK, (and opens OK): Debian 8 - amd64, and Debian **9** - amd64 with # `cd Downloads/ && gdebi ./ted_2.23-1debian8_amd64.deb`